# How to send multiple objects to API and GET the result from API using react js?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am developing a small module in that passenger can able to select the routes and they can see the count of people who are viewing the same route. I want to get this details  by hitting an API. To get the count details I want to send the multiple param's to API. Param's are : start Date, End Date and route details.  I'm new to react js, I have searched for how to pass multiple param's to API by using "Axios" & "async" and get the details from API. Below is the code using "async" didn't get the expected output. I didn't get any clear view. Is there any other method to achieve this. Could any can explain me how to pass multiple value and hit API end point to GET the count details. Thanks in advance.

```
async componentDidMount() {
            let userData = await API.get('/', {
              params: {
                results: 1,
                param: 'sDate =  moment().subtract('1.5', 'hours'),
                        EDate =  moment().subtract('0.5', 'hours'),
                        Routes

              }
            });

            userData = userData.data.results[0];

            const sdate = userData.name.sDate ;
            const edate = userData.picture.EDate ;
            const routes= userData.Routes;

            this.setState({
              ...this.state, ...{
                isLoading: false,
                sdate ,
                edate ,
                routes
              }
            });
          }

        export default App;
```

Comment: param entry doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you API implementation, but you may want to change param into an object like the following, and define the Routes object if you already did not.

```
let userData = await API.get('/', {
    params: {
        results: 1,
        param: {
            sDate: moment().subtract('1.5', 'hours'),
            EDate: moment().subtract('0.5', 'hours'),
            Routes
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If we put `async` keyword at the start of the componentDidMount means, the method return type will be changed to Promise. It may affect the internal behavior of the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

So you can use it like traditional then, catch blocks like below,

```
componentDidMount() {
    API.get('/', {
        params: {
            results: 1,
            param: 'sDate =  moment().subtract('
            1.5 ', '
            hours '),
            EDate = moment().subtract('0.5', 'hours'),
            Routes

        }
    }).then((userData) => {
            userData = userData.data.results[0];

            const sdate = userData.name.sDate;
            const edate = userData.picture.EDate;
            const routes = userData.Routes;

            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                ...{
                    isLoading: false,
                    sdate,
                    edate,
                    routes
                }
            });
        }
    }).catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```